# How to get the property of Object in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hey How Can i get any specific property from the whole object.
I have this query

```
$portfolios = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPortfolios')
    ->findBy(array('user' => '1'));
foreach ($portfolios as $portfolio){
 if($portfolio.isDefault == true){
   $default_portfolio = $portfolio;
 }
  echo $portfolio.name;
}
```

The complete object looks like this

```
MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios Object
(
[id:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => 991654b4-aa73-11e1-bdce-4a7b883b8e17
[portfolioName:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => Umair Portfolio 1
[description:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => Thsi is the description for Umairs portfolio 1
[permalink:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => premalink
[sharingCode:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => asdbnvg123dg
[shared:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => 
[sharedPortfolioCalls:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => 
[isDefault:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => 1
[user:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios:private] => Proxies\MunichInnovationGroupBundleEntityUmUsersProxy Object
```

How can I get the isDefault value ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$obj->property` but if it's private you are not able to access it until you use [`__get()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). Oh, I have not read "symphony". I hope this may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your entity set up correctly with all generated set/get methods, and isDefault is a private property (as it seems so from the var_dump) you can simply use

`if($portfolio->getIsDefault())`

For better method naming I would write a method in the entity:

```
public function isDefault() {
 return $this->isDefault;
}
```

and then use
`if($portfolio->isDefault())`

Comment: I am using it like this but how can I print the name or description in if ?

Comment: So now I am starting to get curious.  Is there some reason you are not allowed to read the documentation?  This is such a trivial question (like several of the others you have posted) that I'm starting to think that maybe you don't know that S2/D2 both have detailed easy to read manuals.

Comment: @Cerad I am a starter at S2/D2 that why I ask so trivial questions. sorry